# Extend DIV width to screen width

Tags: html, css

Especially at low screen resolution, the screen can have an horizontal scrollbar. I want to expand div length to end of the scrollbar. So, width of div may bigger than 100%.

```css
#content{border:2px solid red}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">Test</div>
  <div id="wrap">
       NoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapText
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to expand the `content` width to screen width.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#content{border:2px solid red}
body {
display:table;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">Test</div>
  <div id="wrap">
NoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapTextNoWrapText
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't want to word wrap. I want to expand the content div.

Comment: Check Edit code , body{display:table;} and remove word wrap,

Answer (score 1):

Check it out the answer : do u want this?

https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/mh9juu1w/

I have added the function to calculate the text width
Here

```
$(function(){
$.fn.textWidth = function () {
     $body = $('body');
     $this =  $(this);
     $text = $this.text();
     if($text=='') $text = $this.val();
       var calc = '<div style="clear:both;display:block;visibility:hidden;"><span style="width;inherit;margin:0;font-family:'  + $this.css('font-family') + ';font-size:'  + $this.css('font-size') + ';font-weight:' + $this.css('font-weight') + '">' + $text + '</span></div>';
     $body.append(calc); 
     var width = $('body').find('span:last').width(); 
      $body.find('span:last').parent().remove(); 
     return width; 
    };
wrapWidth = $('#wrap').textWidth();
$('#content').width(wrapWidth);
});
```

Comment: It is OK, but body{display:table;} is enough. I upvoted your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

write the css for the #wrap div and set width 100%;

example

```
div#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to word wrap. I want to expand the content div.

Comment: at least you need to give space between the word

Comment: #wrap content is dynamic. Maybe, it has a table that has a fixed width. I want to expand the content div.